# Routing Table -table driven routing -Am I right?

Tags: routes

[image]

> router R / Router S / Router T
>
> 1 / -       1 / R     1 / S 2 / -       2 / -     2 / S 3 / S       3
>   / -     3 / - 4 / S       4 / T     4 / -

Am I write right answer?
Thanks for view